# When saving data it stored only first iterated value

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Here is my code:

```java
Form<Tenantitem> tenantitemForm = form(Tenantitem.class).bindFromRequest();
String[] itemid = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("idd");
String[] postAction = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("action");

if (postAction == null || postAction.length == 0) {
    return badRequest("You must provide a valid action");
} else {
    String action = postAction[0];
    if ("Add".equals(action)) {
        for (String item: itemid){
            tenantitemForm.get().name =  Tenantitem.findById(item).name;
            tenantitemForm.get().description = Tenantitem.findById(item).description;
            tenantitemForm.get().image_url = Tenantitem.findById(item).image_url;
            tenantitemForm.get().price = Tenantitem.findById(item).price;
            tenantitemForm.get().tenant_id = tenantitemForm.get().tenant_id;
            tenantitemForm.get().tenant_location_id =  tenantitemForm.get().tenant_location_id;
            tenantitemForm.get().tenant_page_id = tenantitemForm.get().tenant_page_id;

            tenantitemForm.get().save();

            System.out.println("name tenant_id"+tenantitemForm.get().name);
            System.out.println("name tenant_location_id"+tenantitemForm.get().tenant_id);
            System.out.println("name tenant_page_id"+tenantitemForm.get().tenant_page_id);
        }


        return redirect(
             routes.Project.pts(loc_id,id)
        );
    } else if ("Cancel".equals(action)) {
        System.out.println("Delete ID:"+id);
        return ok("deleted");
    } else {
        return badRequest("This action is not allowed");
    }
}
```

my views.scala:

```
  @helper.form(routes.Project.addexist(loc_id,pageid,id,pageid)){
        <div class="row-fluid" >
            <div class="span3">

            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <div class="form-inline" id="options1">
                    <input type="button" class="btn"  id="togglein" value="SelectAll" onclick="do_thisin()"/>
                    <label class="control-label offset1">
                        Filter By Name:
                    </label>
                    <input class="span3" type="text" placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>
                <ol id="selectable1">


                    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="tenant_id" value="@id"/>

                    <input type="hidden" name="tenant_location_id" value="@loc_id"/>

                    <input type="hidden" name="tenant_page_id" value="@pageid"/>


                    @for(it <- item){
                    @if(it.tenant_location_id == locid){
                        <li>
                            <div class="well">
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span1">
                                        <input name="idd" class="case" value="@it.id" type="checkbox">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span5">
                                        <img class="img-polaroid span7" src="http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/128400/128483.1.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <dl>
                                        <dt>
                                        <h4>Name:</h4>
                                        </dt>
                                        <dd>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@it.name"/>
                                            <h5>@it.name</h5>
                                        </dd>
                                        <dt>
                                        <h4>Price:</h4>
                                        </dt>
                                        <dd>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="@it.price"/>
                                            <h5>@it.price</h5>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="description" value="@it.description"/>
                                        </dd>
                                    </dl>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    <hr>
                    }
                    }

                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="span5 offset6" >
                    <input  type="submit" name="action" class="btn" value="Add"/>

                    <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn " value="Cancel">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
```

my functionality:
@views:
step:1 -> i need to select multiple items using checkbox.
step:2 -> and i have to get the tenant_id,tenant_location_id,tenant_page_id and item_id.

@controller:
step:3 -> i need to get the values using bind from request, and i have to find the item name,description,price using item_id and get from @model.
step:4 -> finally i have to store the selected values(based on length in checkbox).

When saving data it stored only first iterated value and not stored the remaining selected values. I don't know what exactly happening, and I have also checked data is receiving and it is saving one time

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to do, friend? Can you explain? It seem this statement `Form<Tenantitem> tenantitemForm = form(Tenantitem.class).bindFromRequest();` is useless because you want to overwrite the value on your iteration. And I sugest you dont too often call something like `tenantitemForm.get()` and `Tenantitem.findById(item)` frequently, I suggest to store the value on other variable.

Comment: @Wayan Wiprayoga i need to save multiple times based on my selection in VIEWS.html. Do you have any other suggestion to do that?, and also i need some values from form to store into DB that's why i have used bind `.bindFromRequest();`.

Comment: Can you post your views so I can more understand about what you want to do? So, please update your post by explaining it, friend.

Comment: @WayanWiprayoge I have posted the views kindly review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code maybe a hint for you:

```
Form<Tenantitem> tenantitemForm = form(Tenantitem.class).bindFromRequest();
Tenantitem tenantItem = tenantitemForm.get(); // bind as Tenantitem object

String[] itemid = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("idd");
String[] postAction = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("action");

if (postAction == null || postAction.length == 0) {
    ... // your code
} else {
    ... // your code
    if ("Add".equals(action)) {
        // declare new variable to store the data submitted
        Tenantitem tenantToBeSaved;

        for (String item: itemid) {
            // asign to an Item object?
            tenantToBeSaved = new Tenantitem();
            Item item_assigned = Tenantitem.findById(item)
            tenantToBeSaved.name = item_assigned.name;
            tenantToBeSaved.description = item_assigned.description;
            tenantToBeSaved.image_url = item_assigned.image_url;
            tenantToBeSaved.price = item_assigned.price;
            tenantToBeSaved.tenant_id = tenantItem.tenant_id;
            tenantToBeSaved.tenant_location_id = tenantItem.tenant_location_id;
            tenantToBeSaved.tenant_page_id = tenantItem.tenant_page_id;

            tenantToBeSaved.save();

            ... // rest of your code
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy its working, its better to create object and assigned to it right. thanks for your time.

Comment: Yea friend. Good luck for the project!

Comment: Thanks buddy, it was nice discussing with you.